# define a function of condition of another function

Tags: functions

I want to define a function f(x) such as: *f(x)=f1(x)* if *g(x)<A*, and *f(x)=f2(x*) if *g(x)>A*. The easiest way is of course to solve the equation *g(x)=A* and when you get the solution *x=xo*, then define *f(x)* as: *f(x)=f1(x)* *if x<xo*, and f(x)=f2(x) if *x>xo*. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please give some specific $ f, f_1, f_2 $, and $ g $ functions, as well as some codes you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{f1[x], g[x] > A}, {f2[x], g[x] < A}}]
```

or

```
f[x_] := f1[x] /; g[x] > A
f[x_] := f2[x] /; g[x] < A
```